# Top Scroll / Scroll to top of page not showing in [jobs] wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I would like to add the themes scoll back to the top of the page function to my [jobs] & [resumes] pages in WP job manager.
I added in the following code onto the bottom of the pages where I saved my [shortcode];

```
<a href="#" class="top-scroll"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-up"></i></a>
```

I am using the Specia wordpress theme and when loaded the above snippet appears on the bottom of the page as a paragraph and the top scoll is not working.

Hopefully someone out there can assist.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add any HTML code in your WordPress website for the "Scroll to Top" feature. There are many plugins available in the WordPress repository for this purpose.

You can use this one to achieve your desired results: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpfront-scroll-top/

After installing this plugin, navigate to "Settings" > "Scroll Top" to adjust the settings. 
Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/m6lht1

Let me know if it works for you.